# Bubble sort the numbers from a file in descending order for the first number

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

I want to sort using the "Bubble Sort" algorithm of the 2d array. My array size will be about `array[100000][100000]`. my input number will be n=100,000.

> For now we can use a small size of the array to fix the sorting issue.

1. I need to sort them in descending order for the first number(first number's line).
2. If the first number of 2 values are the same, then I have to sort them according to their second number.
3. Finally I have to output the result into a txt file

Let's' understand using an example. Here, my input looks like this

```
41 11
34 4
69 4
78 6
62 8
5 5
81 3
5 10
```

above our input example and we have a couple of inputs. Now I need to sort them descending orders for the first number. But if the first number of 2 values are the same, then sort them according to their second number.

Example output below,

```
81 3
78 6
69 4
62 8
41 4
34 4
5 10
5 5
```

If anyone can please help me.

I am a beginner so I am trying to input the file manually to solve this sorting problem. I can solve the sorting problem then  I will try to input and out the text.

Something I have tried but not worked. I am still trying to solve it.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int arr[100][100];
    int n,j;
    cin >>n;
    cout << "Please enter a number: " << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   for (int j=i; j<n; j++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "Unsorted array:" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i; j<n; j++)
        {
             cout<<arr[i][j]<<"\t";
        }

    }

    for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i+1; j<=n-1; j++)
        {
            int temp;
            if(arr[i]>arr[j])
            {
                temp=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: arr[100000][100000] is a huge array size, it will not possible. You have to decrease the size.

Comment: check this link, for maximum array size https://discuss.codechef.com/t/maximum-size-of-an-array/3633/4

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr(n, std::vector<int>(n));` and store the numbers in that instead.

Comment: @TedLyngmo still it will not work, the size is huge mentioned in the question, it will get a stack overflow. The maximum array size can 10^7 in normal case.

Comment: @NitaiChandraBanik It will only be a problem if a really huge `n` is entered. Also, allocating the array on the heap is going to work most of the times. The stack allocation OP does will, as you point out, most likely fail.

Comment: I don't know using this array system it works on my teacher's pc

Comment: let's leave the array problem, there I will use vector later. I need to solve the sorting issue.

Comment: Your example input is not valid. @SazidHasanMilon. The input will be n*n(square matrix)

Comment: i will input the numbers from a text file. Here is the original input.txt https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/t8bDvVngnc/

Comment: Are the line numbers actually included in the original input text ? I.e. there are three numbers per line? Or was that just an unfortunate pasting artifact from you, making actually using that as test source input for us worthless? Your stated input sample in the *question* has no line numbers. So which is it?

Comment: Here, 1,2,3 ... n is the line serial number. Here you can see http://prntscr.com/yoi2fc

Comment: Actually, no I can't. And you didn't answer my question. Does each line of the *actual input file* have three numbers or two? Is the *real* data as shown in this post, or as shown in the pastebin four comments ago? They're *not* the same, and it makes a difference.

Comment: 1. input line is 2 numbers in 2 lines. 2. yes this is my real data input file I just uploaded to Pastebin. But there show 3 lines of numbers. [NOTE: the first line of the number is the serial number, it's not an input part}

Comment: OK, now I understand. Next time don't let pastebin format the text; just paste it as raw and leave it at that. As is, it's worthless to try and use, and the other link you provided is literally a *picture* of text, which is even more worthless.

Comment: "_I don't know using this array system it works on my teacher's pc_" - I'm pretty sure that allocating `100000 * 100000 * sizeof(int)` bytes on the stack doesn't work on your teacher's pc either. Making it `100 * 100 * sizeof(int)` will probably work but I would recommend using dynamic memory allocation since you don't know what `n` will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `std::vector<std::array<int,2>>`for your base container. The dynamic growth capabilities of `std::vector` solves your stack space issue, and the `std::array` use gives you tied cell comparison. I.e. you can do this:

```
std::array<int, 2> ar1{1,2}, ar2{1,3};

if (ar1 < ar2) ...
```

and it will do the right thing.  The result then boils down to effectively this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::array<int,2> > v;
    std::size_t n;
    if (std::cin >> n && n > 0)
    {
        std::array<int,2> row;
        while (n-- && std::cin >> row[0] && std::cin >> row[1])
            v.emplace_back(row);

        // bubblesort the content
        std::size_t len = v.size();
        while (len-- > 0)
        {
            bool swapped = false;
            for (std::size_t i=0; i<len; ++i)
            {
                // std::array support multi-cell comparison.
                if (v[i] < v[i+1])
                {
                    // use library swap to swap entire row.
                    std::swap(v[i], v[i+1]);
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }

            // early exit if no swaps happened on the last pass
            if (!swapped)
                break;
        }

        // report final output.
        for (auto const& row : v)
            std::cout << row[0] << ' ' << row[1] << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Input**

```
8
41 11
34 4
69 4
78 6
62 8
5 5
81 3
5 10
```

**Output**

```
81 3
78 6
69 4
62 8
41 11
34 4
5 10
5 5
```

Comment: Really thank you so much. Now I will learn your code and I need to understand it. Then I will take the input from a text file.

Comment: It's not terribly complicated. You can find out more about the template classes used in this code at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/), arguably the very best online reference for C++ on earth. Bookmark that.

Comment: I don't understand your question, but the sort in this code is a simple early-exit bubblesort. It repeatedly sweeps the data set, with each pass comparing adjacent items and swapping them as needed. After each sweep the most-extreme item of that sweep has "bubbled" to the end. The next sweep iteration is reduced by one item, and the process repeats. If, after *any* sweep, we can determine *no* swaps took place, then the overall sequence is completely sorted and we can just stop everything. That is the one (only) redeeming value of bubblesort. It is O(n) if the sequence is sorted.

Comment: It really helped me a lot. Now, I want to input from the text file which we entered manually and generate an output text file

Comment: You could always just use redirection and cheat: `./progname < inputfile > outputfile` . That effectively says, "run `./progname` using the content of `inputfile` as stdin, and all writes to `stdout` go to `outputfile`. Otherwise, it will require checking `argc`, `argv`, standing up [`std::ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) and [`std::ofstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) objects, etc. Usage and instructions on those classes are in the link [I provided earlier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/)

Comment: I tried many ways by adding header `fstream` and used `ofstream outputFunction("outputFile.txt");` output testing but not worked.